# open MYSQL json_array data in SQL_sever

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, sql-server, ssis

I am transferring data from MYSQL to SQL_Server using SSIS and there are around 200 tables.
So I Wrote a dynamic ETL that only takes the name of the table and handles the rest.

but since I had to have a fixed table meta-data I used JSON_array in MYSQL to create a single column from all of the columns except ID something like this:

```
select id 
,JSON_ARRAY(name,cellphone) as JSON
from table
```

because I know the schema of data I wanted to reduce my JSON size and removed table Schema from the JSON.
the created JSON_ARRAY looks like this:

> ["hooman", "12345"]

so after moving to SQL_Server I know I can use `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.json)` like this and read it but then I have to pivot it and that's not efficient at all!
I can see how to open normal JSON so you don't need to pivot your data but I can't find anything for the Array type.

in an ideal world I want something like this:

```
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.json) with(
name  varchar(255) '$[0]' ,
cellphone int '$[1]' )
```

and as a result, I have 2 columns and don't need to pivot my table anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'["hooman", "12345"]';

select json_value(@json, '$[0]') as name, json_value(@json, '$[1]') as cellphone;

select *
from openjson(concat('{"x":', @json, '}')) 
with
(
name  varchar(255) '$.x[0]' ,
cellphone int '$.x[1]'
);

select *
from openjson(concat('[', @json, ']')) 
with
(
name  varchar(255) '$[0]' ,
cellphone int '$[1]'
);
```